# Magento category static block only not working

Tags: php, magento, categories, static-block

If I set a category to products only, it shows products only.

if I set it to static block and products, it shows the static block and products.

If I set it to static block only, it shows static block and products.

That last one doesn't seem right to me. Any idea how I can get it to show only the static block? Or why it insists on showing the products as well, when the backend drop down is on static block only?

Comment: Are you using default magento theme or some other custom theme

Comment: Custom theme. But, it's only for this one category

Answer (score 4):

The answer is: Reindex EVERYTHING.

I had foolishly assumed that the category data would be covered by the index called "Category Flat Data". However, it was not until I reindexed "Product Flat Data" that the category showed correctly.

I don't like to answer my own question, so if anyone can tell me WHY I needed to reindex product data to get the category to display correctly, you get the shiny green checkmark...